# How load paperscript library in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have paperscript code in offset-utils.js file. It contain:

```
var OffsetUtils = new function() { ... }
```

I load it in index.html:

```
  <script src="vendor/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="utils.js"></script>
  <script src="offset-utils.js" type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas"  ></script>      <!--   -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>
```

*paper.js* is included in *vendor.js*

In my code in *index.js* I got error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetUtils is not defined

How I can load my paperscript library for use it in javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're declaring it with `var` then it's local to that source file. You need to export it, like:

```
window.OffsetUtils = new function() ...
```